# Como criar uma classe genérica que receba dados de duas outras classes

Tags: java, genéricos

Tenho três classes, a superclasse `Refeição`, e as classes filhas `Ingrediente` e `Prato`, queria criar uma classe genérica, que recebesse dados das classes filhas para criar um crud (com serialização).

A classe genérica, iria, utilizando os métodos `cadastrar`, `remover`, `editar`, `ler`, `gravar` e `recuperarDados`, os dados pelo `id` (`idIngrediente` e `idPrato`).

---

ex:

```
public void consultarRefeicao(T t) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    recuperaDados();
    for(int i = 0; i < refeicao.size(); i++){
        if(t..getidPrato(ou)getidIngrediente()().equals(refeicao.get(i).getidPrato(ou)getidIngrediente())){
            System.out.println(refeicao.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Como poderia fazer isso de maneira dinâmica passando apenas a classe?
ex: `consultarRefeicao(Prato);` ou `consultarRefeicao(Ingrediente);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua classe genérica seria assim:

```
public class CrudRefeicao<T extends Refeicao> {

    public void cadastrar(T refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public void remover(T refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public void editar(T refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public T ler(long id) { /* ... */ }

    public void gravar(T refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public T recuperarDados(long id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Entretanto, tenho que te alertar que para isso que você esstá fazendo, você provavelmente não precisa de tipos genéricos, podendo fazer isso:

```
public class CrudRefeicao {

    public void cadastrar(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public void remover(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public void editar(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public Refeicao ler(long id) { /* ... */ }

    public void gravar(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public Refeicao recuperarDados(long id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Ou talvez aplicar os genéricos somente a alguns métodos:

```
public class CrudRefeicao {

    public void cadastrar(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public void remover(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public void editar(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public <T extends Refeicao> T ler(Class<T> tipo, long id) { /* ... */ }

    public void gravar(Refeicao refeicao) { /* ... */ }

    public <T extends Refeicao> T recuperarDados(Class<T> tipo, long id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Antes de implementar uma classe genérica, questione-se quanto ao fato de saber se os tipos genéricos vão de fato agregar valor ou apenas introduzir complexidade extra. Uma forma de saber-se isso é perguntar-se que tipo de restrição de tipo importante isso vai trazer e que tipo de problemas o não-uso dos genéricos vai causar:

- No caso de `java.util.List` é porque isso delimita quais são os tipos de objetos que podem ser inseridos na lista ou retirados dela, e ao não usar os tipos genéricos, fica muito fácil poluir-se as listas com tipos heterogêneos.
- O caso de `java.util.Map` é semelhante ao de `java.util.List`, mas com genéricos inddependentes para as chaves e para os valores.
- O caso das interfaces no pacote `java.util.function` é para que quando usadas como lambdas, sejam flexíveis aos tipos de métodos usados.

Nos casos de `java.util.List` e `java.util.Map` é porque em algum lugar do programa, objetos são colocados dentro da coleção e depois lidos a partir dela, e os tipos genéricos servem para amarrar o tipo do dado inserido ao tipo do dado que é lido em outro lugar, nesta ordem necessariamente. Como você está fazendo um CRUD em um banco de dados ou coisa semelhante, você elimina a necessidade de ordenação das operações e com ela talvez elimine a necessidade dos tipos genéricos. Além disso, muitos programas tendem a criar diversas instâncias de `java.util.List` e `java.util.Map` em diversos locais diferentes e para diversas finalidades diferentes. Já no seu caso, me parece que uma única instância singleton resolveria o seu problema.

No seu caso, vejo pouco benefício que seria obtido ao ter-se o `CrudRefeicao` como genérico. Os métodos que retornam `void` poderiam aceitar qualquer tipo de `Refeicao` como parâmetro, e aqui ter a restrição do tipo genérico provavelmente incomodaria muito mais que ajudaria. Para os poucos métodos que fornecem instâncias de `T`, ou você teria que retornar o supertipo de qualquer jeito, ou então pode colocar um parâmetro que indica o tipo desejado.

Com um método `long getId()` e talvez `void setId(long id)` na classe `Refeicao`, talvez sobreescrevendo eles nas subclasses, você provavelmente já elimina a necessidade de ter `CrudRefeicao` como uma classe genérica.

Uma outra forma de analisar é pensando-se se uma instância de `CrudRefeicao<Refeicao>` tem algum valor, se seria usável ou se é alguma coisa completamente diferente de `CrudRefeicao<Ingrediente>` e `CrudRefeicao<Prato>`.

Aliás, fazer `Ingrediente extends Refeicao` e `Prato extends Refeicao` me parece ser uma modelagem inadequada, e portanto isso daqui seria um [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). No meu ponto de vista, o correto seria dizer que uma refeição tem um ou mais pratos e não que uma refeição é um prato. Além disso, o ingrediente definitivamente não é uma refeição, e sim algo que faz parte de uma refeição.

O métodos `consultarRefeicao(Ingrediente)` e `consultarRefeicao(Prato)` não parecem ter sentido, ao menos não com a modelagem que você tem. A refeição no caso já seria o próprio parâmetro passado, e então não haveria nada a ser consultado.

Answer (score 0):

O bom seria você criar um banco de dados por exemplo "restaurante".

então a partir disso você criara as classes beans Igredientes e pratos com os atributos que você precisaria.

e a classe genérica seria o Dao.

Tirando do principio que você teria uma beans para ingrediente, então você teria de criar uma classe Dao ingrediente, a mesma coisa para prato.

Exemplo:

//Para inserir dados na tabela

public void create(Ingrediente i) {

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into Ingrediente ("Atributos") values (?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, p.getNome());
        stmt.setInt(2, p.getNumero());

        stmt.executeUpdate();

        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrediente cadastrado com sucesso!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + ex + "!");
    } finally {
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt);
    }

}

//Método para atualizar dado na tabela.
public void update(Ingrediente i) {

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE Ingrediente SET nome = ?", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, p.getNome());

        stmt.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Atualizado com sucesso!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao atualizar: " + ex);
    } finally {
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt);
    }

}

//Método para deletar.
public void delete(Ingrediente i) {

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("delete from Ingrediente where cd_ingrediente = ?");
        stmt.setInt(1, p.getId());
        stmt.executeUpdate();


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrediente excluído com sucesso!");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao excluir: " + ex);
    } finally {
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt);
    }

}

//Método para buscar informações no banco.
public List<Ingrediente> findAll() {

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    List<Ingrediente> cl = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from Ingrediente);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            Ingrediente c = new Ingrediente();

            c.setId(rs.getInt("id_Ingrediente"));
            c.setNome(rs.getString("nm_Ingrediente"));
            cl.add(c);

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na busca! /n" + ex);
    } finally {
        ConnectionFactory.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
    }

    return cl;

}
```

Link de um projeto onde você poderá ter uma melhor visualização.
https://github.com/andresinho20049/Conex-o-BD---Java